# Compute $I(z):=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2-2z \cos{\pi \alpha}+z^2}$, $z=e^{i \pi \alpha/2}$, $0<\alpha<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $0<\alpha<1$. I nee to compute  $I(e^{\frac{\pi}{2}\alpha \dot{\imath}})$ using contour integrals, where

$$I(z):=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2-2 x z \cos{\pi \alpha}+z^2}.$$

For $z=e^{\frac{\pi}{2}\alpha \dot{\imath}}$, one can factorize
$$x^2-2 x z \cos{\pi \alpha}+z^2=(x-e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi  \alpha})(x-e^{\frac{3 i \pi  \alpha}{2}}).$$
So let us compute

$$I(e^{\frac{\pi}{2}\alpha \dot{\imath}})=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x-e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi  \alpha})(x-e^{\frac{3 i \pi  \alpha}{2}})}$$

We don't know the position of the complex plane the number  $e^{\frac{3 i \pi  \alpha}{2}}$ in the complex plane. But, since $0<\alpha<1$ we know that $e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi  \alpha}$ lies in the fourth quadrant. This suggests the contour $C$: the union of
the line segment $L_R:=\{\arg{z}=0,\, 0\leq |z|\leq R\}$, the  circular arc
$C_R:=\{|z|=R,\, -\pi/2 \leq \arg{z}\leq 0\}$, and the line segment  $V_R:=\{\arg{z}=-\pi/2,\, 0\leq |z|\leq R\}$, taken in the positive sense with $R>1$.

We have from Cauchy's theorem that

$$\int_{C} \frac{dx}{(x-e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi  \alpha})(x-e^{\frac{3 i \pi  \alpha}{2}})}=\frac{2\pi \dot{\imath}}{(e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi  \alpha}-e^{\frac{3 i \pi  \alpha}{2}})}$$

And we have
$$\int_{C_R} \frac{d z}{(z-e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi  \alpha})(z-e^{\frac{3 i \pi  \alpha}{2}})}=\frac{\dot{\imath}}{R}\int_{-\pi/2}^{0}\frac{e^{\dot{\imath}\theta}d \theta}{(e^{\dot{\imath}\theta}-\frac{1}{R}e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi  \alpha})(e^{\dot{\imath}\theta}-\frac{1}{R}e^{\frac{3 i \pi  \alpha}{2}})}\to 0$$
as $R \to \infty$, since
$$\dot{\imath}\int_{-\pi/2}^{0}\frac{e^{\dot{\imath}\theta}d \theta}{(e^{\dot{\imath}\theta}-\frac{1}{R}e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi  \alpha})(e^{\dot{\imath}\theta}-\frac{1}{R}e^{\frac{3 i \pi  \alpha}{2}})}\to e^{-\frac{ i \pi  \alpha}{2}}-1.$$

It remains to compute
$$\int_{V_R} \frac{d z}{(z-e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi \pi\alpha})(z-e^{\frac{3 i \pi  \alpha}{2}})}=i\int_{0}^{-R} \frac{d y}{(i y-e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi\alpha})(iy-e^{\frac{3 i \pi  \alpha}{2}})}$$

But this integral is similar to the integral $I$ we began with.

So, I guess I should look for a better contour may be.

Comment: Assuming $z\in\mathbb{R}$
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2-2xz\cos(\pi a)+z^2}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(x-z\cos(\pi a))^2+(z\sin(\pi a))^2}=\int_{- z\cos(\pi a)}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+(z\sin(\pi a))^2} $$
equals
$$ \frac{1}{z\sin(\pi a)}\int_{-z\cot(\pi a)}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{z\sin(\pi a)}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan\left(z\cot(\pi a)\right)\right) $$

Comment: Obviously you did not get the spirit of the comment: it was made in order to stress that it is not obvious that the integral can be computed through path integration. Hard to get the $\arctan(\cot)$ term from residues. It would have been different if the integration range was $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Comment: I mistook your comment for an answer. Sorry about that.